# What might be a better data structure solution for my purpose? (3d ArrayList of HashSets)

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashset, game-development

My game is a huge-open world, (working on it eventually being infinite),
and I store all the game objects into square sections of the map. This is to only tick/render the objects when the player is in that area.

To accomplish this I am using a "3D" `arraylist` of `hashsets`, the first list being the "row", the second list being the "column" and the third list being the list of all the different types of `hashsets` for the different game objects.

I originally only had a 2d arraylist of hashsets with the hashsets being a generic class, and to render/tick the objects in the correct order I would `instanceof` and then add them to a temp list for each. This was very slow.

I've heard that multi-dimensional lists are frowned upon. What better way might there be to accomplish all this? Trees, etc? I can't use regular arrays as they need to grow in size.

Comment: I don't understand enough of your requirements, but maybe it helps to use a grif of arrays? If the current array does not suffice, add another array next to it. Manage all arays in some extensible outer structure (like a list). EDIT: Thinking of which, the `ArrayList` might help you. It automatically grows and internally uses arrays.

Comment: I would say some sort of list or `ArrayList` although there is no way to really give you any quality advice without knowing more about the game/ what you need.

Comment: @Turtle there isn't much more needed about the game. Just sections of the map that need rendering only when the player is inside them, hence the multi dimensional lists. I can't have "just one" `HashSet` for the section as certain things need rendering over each other, (tiles have to be rendered before anything else for example). I'm just wondering that if a 3d array list of hashsets is way too overly complicated for something that could be accomplished with another data structure more simply.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to access those sets by the player's current position.

I think an efficient way would be to use a multidimensional Map. A good implementation of a multidimensional map is google's Guava Table. Search for it.